# convert variable nature for multiple data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to change the column nature for multiple data frames.
And here is an simple example, which I would like to have both data frames B_1 & B_2 column covert from integer to factor. However I have an error message from the code below.

```
B_1 = data.frame( x=c("01","02","03"))
B_1$x = as.integer(B_1$x)

B_2 = data.frame( x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) )
B_2$x = as.integer(B_2$x)

for (i in 1:2)
    get(paste0("B_",i))[["x"]] <- as.factor(get(paste0("B_",i))[["x"]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get all the datasets in a `list` and then with `mutate_each` convert the columns to `factor` (if there are multiple columns)

```
 library(dplyr)
 lst <- lapply(mget(paste('B', 1:2, sep="_")), 
      function(x) mutate_each(x, funs(factor(.))) )
 str(lst)
 #List of 2
 # $ B_1:'data.frame':    3 obs. of  1 variable:
 #  ..$ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "01","02","03": 1 2 3
 # $ B_2:'data.frame':    7 obs. of  1 variable:
 #  ..$ x: Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

It is better to keep the datasets in a `list`.

Comment: you are right which I got multiple columns in my real data. However, i got an error message saying funtion "mutate_each" cannot be found.

Comment: @RaphaelLi  It is in the `dplyr` package.  You have to load the package first.

Comment: The package cannot be loaded.Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 慏BI?In addition: Warning message:
package 慸plyr?was built under R version 3.3.0 
Error: package or namespace load failed for 慸plyr?

Comment: @RaphaelLi There is some namespace issue.  Are you using the current R version?  I use `dplyr_0.4.3` on `R 3.2.3`.  You can also use `base R`. i..e. `res <- lapply(mget(paste('B', 1:2, sep="_")), function(x) {x[] <- lapply(x, factor);x})`

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am almost there now. I found out dplyr doesnt work since i am using R 3.2.0. May I ask how should I do if I only want to specify unique column in <- lapply(mget(paste('B', 1:2, sep="_")), function(x) {x[] <- lapply(x, factor);x})

Comment: @RaphaelLi In that case, suppose we want to change the 'x' column to factor' `lapply(mget(paste('B', 1:2, sep='_')), transform, x=factor(x))`

Comment: Cheers, i got exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to first make a list with all your B_X data frames and then convert them to factors. Like this:

```
B_1 = data.frame( x=c("01","02","03"))
B_2 = data.frame( x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) )

li = list()
for (i in 1:2) {li = c(li, get(paste0("B_",i)))}
for (k in 1:2) {li[[k]] = as.factor(li[[k]])}
```

this will return:

```
> li
$x
[1] 01 02 03
Levels: 01 02 03

$x
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, it works but how can I put the list to the right data frame respectively ?

Comment: How did you define each B_X initially? One by one? Why not use the list instead? That is, if you need to use B_5 and B_43 then do `li[[5]]` and `li[[43]]`.

Comment: i understand that, my idea is to have all multiple database merge together to form a large dataset, that 's why I would like have to data frame instead of using list. And i do have more than one column